# Helm 3 install for resouces that exist

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

when running `helm install` (helm 3.0.2)

I got the following error: Error: 
`rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: existing resource conflict: kind: PodSecurityPolicy, namespace: , name: po-kube-state-metrics`

But I don't find it and also In the error im not getting the ns, How can I remove it ?

when running `kubectl get all --all-namespaces` I see all the resources but not the `po-kub-state-metrics` ... it also happen to other resources, any idea?

I got the same error to: `monitoring-grafana` entity and the result of 
`kubectl get PodSecurityPolicy --all-namespaces` is:

`monitoring-grafana                             false               RunAsAny   RunAsAny           RunAsAny    RunAsAny    false            configMap,emptyDir,projected,secret,do`

Comment: Can you add the result of `kubectl get PodSecurityPolicy --all-namespaces` to the question body?

Comment: @KamolHasan - please see my update

Comment: Did you already install this or similar chart to your cluster? What chart did you use? Are you using Minikube or Kubeadm?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure you've successfully uninstalled the helm `release`, before reinstalling.

To list all the releases, use:

```
$ helm list --all --all-namespaces
```

To uninstall a release, use:

```
$ helm uninstall <release-name> -n <namespace>
```

You can also use `--no-hooks` to skip running hooks for the command:

```
$ helm uninstall <release-name> -n <namespace> --no-hooks
```

If uninstalling doesn't solve your problem, you can try the following command to cleanup:

```
$ helm template <NAME> <CHART> --namespace <NAMESPACE> | kubectl delete -f -
```

Sample:

```
$ helm template happy-panda stable/mariadb --namespace kube-system | kubectl delete -f -
```

Now, try installing again.

**Update:**

Let's consider that your chart name is `mon` and your release name is `po`. Since you are in the charts directory (`.`) like below:

```
.
├── mon
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── one.yaml
│   │   ├── two.yaml
│   │   ├── three.yaml
│   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   ├── NOTES.txt
│   └── values.yaml
```

Then you can skip the helm repo name (i.e. stable) in the `helm template` command. `Helm` will use your `mon` chart from the directory.

```
$ helm template po mon --namespace mon | kubectl delete -f -
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this give me some direction. if I install the helm chart with the current dir `.` like this ` helm upgrade --install  mon--namespace mon . -f values.yaml` , how should I delete it in this case ?

Comment: I was getting a similar error. `helm lint` raised issues which i had to go fix.

Answer (score 7):

i've got the same issue while deploying Istio. So i did

```
kubectl get clusterrole
kubectl get clusterrolebinging
kubectl delete mutatingwebhookconfiguration istio-sidecar-injector
kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfiguration istio-galley
kubectl delete namespace <istio-namespace>
```

and when deleted all and started, it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error with CRDs objects. I used this chart on Github, and to prevent this error I used the `--skip-crds` flag. Maybe the project that you are using has something like this:
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/sparkoperator#configuration

Comment: Thanks, this answer solved my problem. Have had the same issue with CRDs. If i wanted to install a chart with crds, which are already existed on my cluster, helm failes with the errormessage ```rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install```. I already tried the ```--skip-crds```, but didnt took into account, that the corresponding helm templates containg the crd definitions  have to be placed in a folder called ```crds```. Your link led me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 4):

So nor the `--force` or no the other options help. Here is the error that I was getting.

```
Release "develop-myrelease" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: existing resource conflict: namespace: , name: develop-myrelease, existing_kind: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, Kind=ClusterRoleBinding, new_kind: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1, Kind=ClusterRoleBinding
```

So I just delete clusterrolebinding and its work.

```
kubectl get clusterrolebinding | grep develop-myrelease
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding develop-myrelease
```

and run the deployment again.

Answer (score 2):

for my case able to successfully upgrade my build with --force

```
Mulhasans-MacBook-Pro:helm-tuts mulhasan$ helm upgrade --install --force  api-streamingserver ./api-streamingserver
```

This will help for the same Release if you are doing with different release choose a different name for conflicting resources as of now Helmv3.x doesn't have option for CRDs --skip-crds is removed in Helmv3.x

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading to helm 3, ensure you can run helm 2 and helm 3 separately. Example

```
helm2 list
helm3 list
```

After this, if you will try to install a helm chart within helm 3, that error will pops-up because it exists in helm 2.

Use helm2to3 plugin to upgrade to Helm3:
https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3

I follow this exactly and I got no issues

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours on bugs that are related to the error:

> Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists...

I have 3 simple conclusions:

1 ) Resources from previous deployments (via kubectl or helm) might exists in the cluster.

2 ) Use an advanced administrative/debugging tool like [k9s](https://github.com/derailed/k9s#the-command-line) or [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/) to view ALL cluster resources (instead of `kubectl get` / `helm ls`).

3 ) Usally, the resource names which are specified in the error has a meaning - search directly for them and see if they can be deleted.